# How do you search a string in Irvine Assembly Language and replace it with a substring?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, substring

I am writing a program that reads a string then searches for certain keywords, like "cat", and replaces it with "dog". I am just unsure as how to start it. What code will I have to use?

Comment: out of curiosity what is the irvine asm and why are you using it?

Comment: It is just a sub language of asm I suppose. I am taking an assembly language course and this is what they decided to teach for whatever reason. It is not much different from the basics, from what I understand

Comment: cool! so they just threw this problem at you and said to go post it on stackoverflow ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 8-bit characters it's broadly like this, there are many ways to implement it:

1. Set `si` to point to the first character of the string.
2. `mov al,[si]`
3. `repnz scasb` to find the first match of the first character.
4. Store the address somewhere.
5. Set `di` to point to the first character of the replacement string (`'dog'` in this case).
6. Set `cx/ecx/rcx` to string length.
7. `repz cmpsb`
8. Check that `cx/ecx/rcx` is zero and last characters match.
9. If yes, it's a match, so copy `'dog'` to the address stored with `rep movsb` (set pointers `si` and `di` first). Do note that this approach only works if the replace string is no longer than the original string. If it's longer, you may need to reserve a new block of memory to avoid a buffer overflow. If it's not a match, backtrack `si` to the stored address, increment `si` by 1 (by 2 for 16-bit characters), and jump to 2. (`mov al,[si]`). You need to also check here when you have reached the end of the string.
10. Ready. Or, if you want to replace all, as in sed `s/cat/dog/g`, loop from 1, set pointer (`si`) first (depending on how you want your regex engine to work).

For UTF-8 (16-bit characters) replace the following: `scasb` -> `scasw`, `cmpsb` -> `cmpsw`, `movsb` -> `movsw`, `al` -> `ax`.

For 32-bit code, replace all references to `si` with `esi` and all references to `di` with `edi`.

For 64-bit code, replace all references to `si` with `rsi` and all references to `di` with `rdi`.